# my Pyramid does not like Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, openshift, pyramid

I have a Pyramid server on an Openshift Python 3 cartridge that does not like the module Pandas, but I cannot figure how to figure out why it is so.

In `setup.py` the method `setuptools.setup` is called with the argument `install_requires` with a few modules (such as `pyramid`,`biopython`,`numpy`), which run fine. But when I add `pandas` it fails. This is what it says during pushing (✱ = censoring added for security):

```
remote: Installing collected packages: six, python-dateutil, pytz, pandas
remote:   Found existing installation: six 1.3.0
remote:     Not uninstalling six at /opt/rh/python33/root/usr/lib/python3.3/site-packages, outside environment /var/lib/openshift/✱✱✱✱✱/python/virtenv/venv
remote:   Running setup.py install for pandas: started
remote:     Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
remote:     Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
remote:     Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
remote:     Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
remote:     Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
remote:     Running setup.py install for pandas: still running...
Connection to pedel2-matteoferla.rhcloud.com closed by remote host.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
error: error in sideband demultiplexer
To ssh://pedel2-matteoferla.rhcloud.com/~/git/pedel2.git/
   ✱✱✱  master -> master
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://✱✱✱✱@pedel2-matteoferla.rhcloud.com/~/git/pedel2.git/'
```

Adding a `requirements.txt` file does not affect it due to permission issues seen also with when I ssh into the server and pip install it manually. Namely `/var/lib/openshift` isn't my virtual environment.

```
remote: Activating virtenv
remote: Checking for pip dependency listed in requirements.txt file..
remote: The directory '/var/lib/openshift/✱✱✱✱/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
```

Pip3 within the virtual python does the same.

```
cd /python/virtenv/venv/bin/
./pip3 install pandas
```

Easy_install does it right but has no permission, so this approach is wrong anyway.

```
pedel2-matteoferla.rhcloud.com bin]\> ./easy_install pandas
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 122] Disk quota exceeded: '/var/lib/openshift/✱✱✱✱/python/virtenv/venv/lib/python3.3/site-packages/test-easy-install-247598.write-test'
```

I assume I ought to solve the problem with setuptools module. Which means I need to figure out why from there. But I am stuck.

**EDIT.** It is not my disk quota.

```
Matteos-Air-3:pedel2 matteo$ rhc show-app pedel2 --gears quota

Gear                     Cartridges   Used Limit
------------------------ ---------- ------ -----
✱✱✱✱                     python-3.3 268 MB  1 GB
```

Comment: what Pandas version are you trying to install?

Comment: Latest. This is the first time I try to put pandas up there, so my guess it cannot be a version thing.

Comment: Also I have reset the server from scratch some 3 times to undo damage in ssh —too many failed pips do flood the cache and I do get to the limit of 1 GB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a few issues.

1. size issue - it's difficult to reproduce it. But maybe we don't need it (see details below)
2. Modern Pandas versions are NOT compatible with Python 3.3 - see [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11273)

I'd recommend you to use "ready to go" distributives like Anaconda with already preinstalled numpy, pandas and lot more.

Beside that - don't overwrite systme Python - it might cause another problems.

Just [install Anaconda into a separate directory](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install-linux.html) and set Anaconda environment everytime you want to use it.

PS alternatively you can have [Anaconda as Docker](https://www.continuum.io/blog/developer-blog/anaconda-and-docker-better-together-reproducible-data-science)

Comment: I saw there is an OpenShift cartridge for Anaconda. I am going to give that a go. Thanks!

Comment: @MatteoFerla, glad i could help :-)